# Tell what disk/volume a file lives on

Tags: macos, filesystems

In macos [or potentially any unix], is there any way to ask which volume a file is stored on?

For example, `/Users/me/Photos/picture123.jpg` lives on `/dev/disk1s5`.

I can use the `mount` command to see where each disk is mounted in the filesystem. I can pick the longest prefix for each file, but I don't think that is safe in the presence of symlinks/hard links. For example the above path is also available at `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/...`

(What I'm really trying to do is generate some "universal" path for files so that I can store references to them in a database while keeping track of which physical drive they exist on)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "df"

[DF Man Page](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/df1.html)

**Example**:

`df ./Music | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1}'`

**Output**

`/dev/disk1s2`

Answer (score 1):

On macOS you can use BSD [`stat`](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/stat.1.html) to get the device name.

```
$ stat -f '%Sd' ~
disk1s1
```

And you can use GNU [`stat`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html) to get the mount point.<sup>1</sup>

```
$ gstat --format '%m' ~
/
```

`/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is just a symbolic link to `/`.<sup>2</sup>

```
$ ls -l /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1 May 20 23:32 /Volumes/Macintosh HD -> /
```

---

<sub>1. GNU stat is available on macOS if [coreutils](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) is installed</sub>
<sub>2. For details see [here](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/09/07/wheres-my-data-volume-navigating-boot-volumes-in-macos-10-15-11-12/)</sub>